# Where is com.intellij.modules.lang defined

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

This should be an easy one, but it's driving me mad. I'm new to implementing plugins, and one that I'm looking at has the following dependency:

```
<depends>com.intellij.modules.lang</depends>
```

I cloned the intellij-community project and was expecting to see this defined as an extensionPoint in one of the many `plugin.xml` files in the project, but either I can't search correctly or it is somewhere else.

Anybody knows where I can find this definition?

Answer (score 1):

I'm still no expert in plugin development, but I think I figured out parts of my problem.

First, I was wrong about *com.intellij.modules.lang* having to be defined as an extension point. Name of extensions need to have corresponding extension points, not dependencies.

Then *com.intellij.modules.lang* is defined in a 
`<module>` 
tag in a few xml files in the intellij source code, which is part of the SDK used by this project. One such file is *platform/platform-resources/src/META-INF/PlatformLangPlugin.xml*. Now I need to familiarize myself with the concept of modules, but the original question is not moot.

Thanks to anyone who spent a few seconds thinking about this problem.

Comment: Why do you care where and how this is defined? The 'com.intellij.modules.*' dependencies are only used to specify which IntelliJ Platform-based products your plugin is compatible with, as described in http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/plugin_compatibility.html